# Подсчёт всех значений, отключённых input'ов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно решить небольшую задачку на js+jQuery.

На странице есть такие инпуты:

```
<input type="text" class="price" disabled="disabled" value="100" />
<input type="text" class="price" value="200" />
<input type="text" class="price" value="300" />
<input type="text" class="price" disabled="disabled" value="400" />
<input type="text" class="price" disabled="disabled" value="500" />
```

Нужно их всех найти, исключить те инпуты, которые отключены (disabled), и посчитать их значение, в данном примере скрипт должен выдать 500. Как это реализовать на jQuery?

Пока что функция выглядит так:

```
function total() {
    var counts = $('input.price:enabled').length;
    if (counts > 0) {
        $('.total_price').html('Вы выбрали ' + counts + ' платных элементов, на сумму ' + summ + ' рублей');
    }
}
```

Как посчитать переменную summ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function total(){
   var total=0;
   $("input:enabled").each(function(){
      total=total+$(this).val();
   });
   return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var summ = 0;
    var elem = $('input.price:enabled');
    var counts = elem.length;
    $.each(elem, function(){
        summ += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
    })
    $('.total_price').html('Вы выбрали '+counts+' платных элементов, на сумму '+summ+' рублей');
</script>
```